# tabular glossary in latex

Tags: tables, glossaries, acronyms

I am looking for a command on how to create a table of abbreviations/acronyms as it was done in the picture below

[image]

Comment: check glossaries package https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf